# Recursive Shell Script and file extensions issue

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem with this script. The script is supposed to go trough all the files and all sub-directories and sub-files (recursively). If the file ends with the extension .txt i need to replace a char/word in the text with a new char/word and then copy it into a existing directory. The first argument is the directory i need to start the search, the second is the old char/word, third the new char/word and fourth the directory to copy the files to. The script goes trough the files but only does the replacement and copies the files from the original directory.  Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

funk(){
  for file in `ls $1`
  do
    if [ -f $file ]
    then
      ext=${file##*.}
      if [ "$ext" = "txt" ]
      then
        sed -i "s/$2/$3/g" $file
        cp $file $4
      fi
    elif [ -d $file ]
    then
      funk $file $2 $3 $4
    fi
  done
}

if [ $# -lt 4 ]
then
  echo "Need more arg"
  exit 2;
fi

cw=$1
a=$2
b=$3
od=$4
funk $cw $a $b $od
```

Comment: Your code will break as soon as there's a file/directory name containing spaces. See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a more detailed explanation why you should never use `ls` the way you do in your code.

Comment: Your question doesn't make clear what isn't working. Maybe it's jut my eyes, but your requirements and your description of what the script does, seem identical.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As pointed out, looping over find output is not a good idea. It also doesn't support slashes in search&replace.

Check [gniourf_gniourf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391527/1731713).

---

How about using `find` for that?

```
 #!/bin/bash

 funk () {
     local dir=$1; shift
     local search=$1; shift
     local replace=$1; shift
     local dest=$1; shift

     mkdir -p "$dest"
     for file in `find $dir -name *.txt`; do
         sed -i "s/$search/$replace/g" "$file"
         cp "$file" "$dest"
     done
 }

 if [[ $# -lt 4 ]] ; then
     echo "Need 4 arguments"
     exit 2;
 fi

 funk "$@"
```

Though you might have files with the same names in the subdirectories, then those will be overwritten. Is that an issue in your case?

Comment: `find` should not be used in that way. Use `-exec` instead of a `for` loop, that will break whenever a filename contains whitespace: `mkdir -p "$4"; find "$1" -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i "s/$2/$3/g {} \; -exec cp {} "$4"/ \;`

Comment: This will also break if the `search` or `replace` character happens to be a slash.

Comment: And why create that destination directory so often?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf True. I was mainly pointing out a better way to use `find` here, not a full solution.

Answer (score 6):

You're using a lot of bad practices here: lack of quotings, you're parsing the output of `ls`... all this will break as soon as a filename contains a space of other funny symbol.

You don't need recursion if you either use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s `globstar` optional behavior, or `find`.

Here's a possibility with the former, that will hopefully show you better practices:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

funk() {
    local search=${2//\//\\/}
    local replace=${3//\//\\/}

    for f in "$1"/**.txt; do
        sed -i "s/$search/$replace/g" -- "$f"
        cp -nvt "$4" -- "$f"
    done
}

if (($#!=4)); then
    echo >&2 "Need 4 arguments"
    exit 1
fi

funk "$@"
```

The same function funk using `find`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

funk() {
    local search=${2//\//\\/}
    local replace=${3//\//\\/}

    find "$1" -name '*.txt' -type f -exec sed -i "s/$search/$replace/g" -- {} \; -exec cp -nvt "$4" -- {} \;
}

if (($#!=4)); then
    echo >&2 "Need 4 arguments"
    exit 1
fi

funk "$@"
```

In `cp` I'm using

- the `-n` switch: no clobber, so as to not overwrite an existing file. Use it if your version of `mv` supports it, unless you actually want to overwrite files.
- the `-v` switch: verbose, will show you the moved files (optional).
- the `-t` switch: `-t` followed by a directory tells to copy into this directory. It's a very good thing to use `cp` this way: imagine instead of giving an existing *directory*, you give an existing *file*: without this feature, this file will get overwritten several times (well, this will be the case if you omit the `-n` option)! with this feature the existing file will remain safe.

Also notice the use of `--`. If your `cp` and `sed` supports it (it's the case for GNU `sed` and `cp`), use it always! it means *end of options now*. If you don't use it and if a filename start with a hyphen, it would confuse the command trying to interpret an option. With this `--`, we're safe to put a filename that may start with a hyphen.

Notice that in the *search* and *replace* patterns I replaced all slashes `/` by their escaped form `\/` so as not to clash with the separator in `sed` if a slash happens to appear in *search* or *replace*.

Enjoy!